# Is Upgrading SharePoint To Enterprize A Good Idea or Go With Office 365

Tags: office-365

sorry for not being very specific in my title but it would be a mile long.

My situation is this. The Company I work for has been very comfortable using SharePoint Foundation 2013 but now finding the need to do more then create List and Libraries. I've shown them what Workflows can do for them however and that they can be used as a much cheaper alternative to purchasing a CRM. I know the Workflows are limited in Foundation but I can get them to upgrade to Enterprise 2013.

How does this sound ? Am I on the right track ?

We have a Division of the Company that is using Office365 and they have access to SharePoint. The cost of this is attractive and seems like a nice alternative to going with the Enterprise Edition.

The Big Question here is our Email. Can we keep our Email on our Corp Server. I wouldn't want to divide up the Company with SharePoint users on a separate server with a different email address.

Hope you can shed some light and thank you for your time.

Comment: where are you storing the user e-mails? sharepoint can pull data from active directory and you can have all user info in the same place

Comment: Sorry I'm unsure where your going with this but our Foundation version is not set up to receive emails but will send. Any requests for changes to sites or adding, deleting and updating list and libraries come to my company email address as I am responsible. It is hooked to active directory and it's used primarily for Permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are on the right track. I've built several CRM systems in SharePoint as an alternative to large expensive CRM packages with functionality that was not needed. Upgrading to Enterprise is certainly viable, and you will have much more functionality to utilize.

Yes, with Office 365 you can keep user mailboxes on your on premise server, simply don't migrate them to Exchange online. In addition, you have the ability to deploy a hybrid Exchange environment. Learn more about the advantages of hybrid Exchange deployments here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200581(v=exchg.150).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I now know I have a choice of 2 options